# Rest Service Mocking in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I created a Mock service in SoapUI. Service runs perfectly if hit by URL 
http://localhost:8025/magento_1.9/index.php/phonegapapp/users/login/sucessful.json?email=sarvagya.pandey@netsolutionsindia.com&password=123456
But i don't need **sucessful.json** in URL and if i remove this Mockup service stops please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by you "don't need sucessful.json"

You can add that as a variable if you wish to use multiple files, eg
http://localhost:8025/magento_1.9/index.php/phonegapapp/users/login/<jsonStatus>

Comment: @ECiurleo Thanks for your response. As i am bigneer with SOAPUI was facing issue when i have to send some param in query string. Before appending query string i have to append response name "Successful.json" in the url otherwise showing dispath error. But luckily i have fixed that issue.

Comment: Excellent :)  

May be worth adding your solution onto this question so others with similar issues in the future may also be helped